# react tool kit with typescripts, reducers return type

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am using redux toolkit for my state management with TypeScripts. The StateSlice reducers expect a return type, I tried to type it as what the expected return object should be but its just does not work the only way it works if i set the return type as `any`

for example in my StateSlice a one of the reducer looks like this.

```
deleteCard: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<DeleteCard>): any => {  return {
    cards: [...state.cards.filter((card) => card["id"] !== payload)],   }; },
```

As you can see the return type is set as any... i have gone through a lot of google articles for example `redux toolkit reducer return type` and the only thing i can find is how to type the payload using `PayloadAction`

So the question is how do i type reducers return type

Comment: What was the TS error? Why can't you use type inference? Have you seen this https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createslice?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write mutating logic in RTK reducers and not return anything: [Writing Reducers with Immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers)

But even if you return something, you should just not annotate a return type. It's already set by `createSlice` and it will warn you if you return something wrong it will warn you without any need for an annotation.

Correct code would be either

```
// preferred immer-mutable approach

deleteCard: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<DeleteCard>) => {
  const index = state.cards.findIndex((card) => card["id"] == payload))
  if (index != -1) {
    state.cards.splice(index, 1)
  }
},
```

or

```
deleteCard: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<DeleteCard>) => { 
  return {
    cards: [...state.cards.filter((card) => card["id"] !== payload)],
  };
},
```